# History of the definition of smooth manifold with boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, ho.history-overview, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

I am trying to determine the earliest source for the definition of smooth ($C^\infty$) manifold with boundary. Milnor and Stasheff (1958) give a definition, but a scrutiny of that definition shows it to be incomplete (because they fail to define what smoothness means in that context).

What is the earliest known reference that is rigorous by modern standards?

Comment: Maybe p. 64 of Thom, [**Quelques propriétés globales des variétés différentiables**](http://dx.doi.org/10.5169/seals-22612), Comment. Math. Helv. 28, 17-86 (1954). [ZBL0057.15502](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0057.15502)?

Comment: You may want to check papers of H. Whitney from late 1930s and early 1940s. He certainly worked with manifolds with boundary (which he called partial manifolds), and  he was comparting $C^r$ structures for different $r$ and proving Whitney embedding theorems, so he was aware of the issues.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler  My French is not great, but I couldn't find it in that reference. Do you know where it might be in the paper?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I did. I couldn't find it.  I'll check again.

Comment: @JohnKlein As I said, p. 64. The top 10 lines define a *manifold $M^{n+1}$ with boundary $V^n$*; later p. 66 defines differentiable maps between manifolds with boundary.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Thank you. But I am not entirely convinced that this a rigorous definition. He doesn't clarify what he means by the differentiable structure at the boundary points.

Comment: Right, his b) says a bit elliptically that at boundary points “there are charts” mapping  $M$ to a closed half-space and restricting on the manifolds $M-V$ (resp. $V$) to charts with values in the open half-space (resp. the boundary hyperplane) — leaving talk about equivalent atlases of such charts to the reader. Maybe his *Quelques propriétés des variétés-bords* ([1952](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=51511)) had more details?

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler I will check *Quelques propriétés des variétés-bords.*

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler, I don't have access to that paper. But I do have access to another one, given in Seminar Bourbaki, which makes the same elliptical definition: 
*Sur les variétés-bords,*

http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1951-1954__2__357_0.pdf

Comment: What source would you recommend for a modern rigorous definition with discussion of the differentiable structure on the boundary?

Comment: @MattF. Guillemin and Pollack's, *Differential Topology* is rigorous.

Comment: So the best rigorous discussion is for manifolds embedded in $R^n$?

Comment: @MattF. No, I am not stating that. There is the transition function method and there is the method which uses maps from a open subsets in upper half $n$-space. Both methods can be made made rigorous. Milnor and Stasheff (1958) are not rigorous but Milnor later corrects this lack of rigor in *Topology from the differentiable viewpoint* (1965).   Is this the earliest rigorous definition? I do not know.

Comment: But curiously, both Milnor 1965 and Guillemin and Pollack begin their definitions by saying “$X \subset R^k$ is called a smooth $m$-manifold with boundary if...” / “A subset $X$ of $R^N$ is a $k$-dinensional manifold with boundary if...”

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with the definition in Milnor-Stasheff. That they fail to explain what is a smooth map from an open subset of a half-space to $\mathbb R^n$? This has been standard since [H. Whitney, Differentiable functions defined in closed sets. I, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 36 (1934), no. 2, 369–387] considered much more delicate issues. Incidentally, the pseudogroup definition of a smooth (and also geometric) structure goes back to [O. Veblen and J. H. C. Whitehead, The Foundations of Differential Geometry] https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1933-39-05/S0002-9904-1933-05600-8/.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I just checked that paper. The definition given there is not the usual one I'm used to, say from Guillemin and Pollack. Whitney defines smoothness on a closed subset $A$ of $\Bbb R^n$ by the existence of a Taylor expansion on $A$. This is not what we teach our students.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek What I'm really looking for I guess is the first use of the definition which says that $f\: A \to \Bbb R^k$ is smooth, where $A\subset \Bbb R^n$, (no assumptions on $A$) if at each $x\in A$ there is a local extension of $f$ to a smooth map defined on an open neighborhood of $x$ in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: I think what we teach our students is not directly relevant. My point was that by mid 1930s Whitney had a firm grip on differentiability of functions defined on closed sets of $\mathbb R^n$. Perhaps, the reference I gave is not the best one; the story can be traced from   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek thanks for the references. I was not aware of them. My question then morphs into the following: when did the translation occur from Whitney's definition into the modern (1960s) definition? Was the 1960s definition available in the 1950s?